# Tensorflow: Normal distribution broadcasting

Tags: tensorflow

I define batch of two normal distributions:

```
dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(mu=[1., 2.], sigma=10.)
```

Then I want to evalutate pdf of each of this distribution on each of points [0., 1., 2., 3.]. Unfortunately

```
dist.pdf([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

make an error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 2
```

How can I evaluate it in a simple way and have tensor of shape (2, 4) as an output?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `dist.prob([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])` tensorflow tries to evaluate the pdf at each entry in the list in a different normal distribution, but your batch only has two. The solution is to evaluate the pdf at each value and then stack the tensors together:

```
dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(loc=[1., 2.], scale=10.)
tf.stack([dist.prob(m) for m in [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]],axis=1)
```

This yields a tensor with the required shape:

```
<tf.Tensor 'stack_4:0' shape=(2, 4) dtype=float32>
```